# How to install ipython qtconsole?

Tags: package-management, ipython

I get this error when launching `qtconsole`.

I already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libzmq-dev
sudo pip install pyzmq
sudo pip install pygments
sudo apt-get install libqt4-core libqt4-gui libqt4-dev
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on? I am quite new to this system and I am probably missing something really basic...thank you

```
david@Hyperion:~$ ipython qtconsole
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ipython==4.1.0.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-4.1.0.dev0-py2.7.egg/IPython/__init__.py", line 118, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 591, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-4.1.0.dev0-py2.7.egg/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 305, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-4.1.0.dev0-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/application.py", line 386, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-4.1.0.dev0-py2.7.egg/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 300, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 487, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 418, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython_genutils/importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
ImportError: No module named qtconsole.qtconsoleapp
```

Comment: Shot in the blue: `sudo apt-get install ipython-qtconsole` or `sudo pip install qtconsole`

Answer (score 15):

You need an additional install:

```
sudo pip install qtconsole
```

or via apt

```
sudo apt-get install ipython-qtconsole   # for Python2
```

---

*Why?*

```
apt-file search qtconsoleapp
```

or read [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=qtconsoleapp%20&mode=filename&suite=trusty&arch=any).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this and for solving my problem in 2 minutes!

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: @A.B. `[Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!`  **;-)**

Comment: do you know is this something new? I do not recall having to install `qtconsole` separately

Comment: @dashesy I have added the "Why?" at the end of my answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## To install

```
pip install pyqt5 qtconsole
```

## Run

```
jupyter qtconsole
```

## Details

The command `ipython qtconsole` is deprecated in favour of `jupyter qtconsole`. For some reason, `pip install qtconsole` doesn't install the dependency `pyqt5`. I think this has to do something with the `qtconsole` being able to use different libraries for display, including `pyside`?

This was tested on Ubuntu 17.10 and Python 3.